# EWS Management API - Object reference not set to an instance of an object when create appointment

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to create appointment with EWS Management API.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
service.Url = new Uri(url);

service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, pass, domain); 

Folder calendar_Folder = Folder.Bind(service, new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, usermailbox));

Appointment meeting = new Appointment(service);
meeting.Subject = "test";
meeting.Body = "test body";
meeting.Start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
meeting.End = meeting.Start.AddHours(2);
meeting.RequiredAttendees.Add(att1);
meeting.RequiredAttendees.Add(att2);
meeting.RequiredAttendees.Add(att3);

meeting.Save(calendar_Folder.Id, SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);
```

When I execute this code, I get this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Stack trace:

> at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.WrapStream(Stream responseStream, String contentEncoding)
>      at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetResponseStream(IEwsHttpWebResponse response)
>      at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ProcessWebException(WebException webException)
>      at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request)
>      at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest& request)
>      at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.InternalExecute()
>      at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalCreateItems(IEnumerable`1 items, FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandling)
>      at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.CreateItem(Item item, FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode)
>      at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.InternalCreate(FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode)
>      at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment.Save(FolderId destinationFolderId, SendInvitationsMode sendInvitationsMode)

What is wrong?
The user have rights to create appointments.

The same case occures, when I'am trying to update or delete user's appointments. User is organizer, e.g. owner of this appointments.

Also I've tried to use `service.ImpersonatedUserId` with the same result.

Comment: what version of Exchange are you using, it sounds like the error maybe coming from the server I would suggest you enable tracing https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devmsg/2015/10/02/ewshow-to-enable-ews-request-and-response-tracing-in-powershell-script-using-ews-managed-api/ and check what the server response actually is.

Comment: @glen-scales, Exchange 2019. The problem was in API's bug. I use this fix from last pull request: https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/pull/230. Create appointments now works. But when I'am trying to update/delete meeting with impersonalisation, I recereived another exception: "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again., The process failed to get the correct properties.". I am shure that creaditals are right and the impersonated user is organizer.